# String-append not working; keeps overwriting previous strings

Tags: string, lisp, scheme, append

I am trying to do a simple task of appending a number to a string multiple times, and hoping that this will build a string.

But it is not working, each call to `(string-append ....)` seems to do nothing at all.

Here is my code:

```
(define myString "")
(string-append (number->string 4) myString)
(string-append (number->string 5) myString)
(string-append (number->string 6) myString)
(string-append (number->string 7) myString)
(display myString)
```

this displays:

"4"

"5"

"6"

"7"

and a blank line for `(display myString)`

What am I doing wrong?

also if I do it the other way like so it doesn't work either:

```
(define myString "")
(string-append myString (number->string 4))
(string-append myString (number->string 5))
(string-append myString (number->string 6))
(string-append myString (number->string 7))
(display myString)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string-append` does not alter an existing string; it returns a new string that is the result of the operation.

If this seems unusual, consider the addition operator, `+`. When I write

`3+4`

I'm not changing `3` into `7`, just returning the result of the operation.

So, in your case, if you write

```
(define my-string (string-append (number->string 4) (number->string 5)))
(display my-string)
```

You should see

```
45
```

To advise you further, it might help to know where you're heading with this.

Comment: well its a program to convert infix notation to postfix notation.
i am using a stack from this website : http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs201/Fall_2007/materials/pdfs/stacks.pdf

i read in the users input, and convert it to a list of characters.  then i go through and check if the first charcter is a number, bracket or operator and run an algorithm on it



so if i want to have a global string, that numbers are being added onto, how would i do this?

i have declared a string above my function, but im not sure how to reassign the return value of 
(string-append)

Comment: I advise you to reconsider your design. You can write your program so that it simply returns a new string rather than using global values.

Comment: You are right, i should redesign it to avoid global variable - i am so used to OOP languages lol!

I ended up using a stack from that link before to store the dynamic variable that i initially wanted to append to the string, and so far so good - i have a program that takes a infix string ((1+3)*4) and spits out a postfix expression 1 3 + 4 *.

No all i need to learn is how to print off a list without it having the ( ) parenthesis around it!

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

The expression `(string-append  (number->string 4) myString)` evaluates to `"4"`, which is why your code prints `4`.  Similarly, `(string-append  (number->string 5) myString)` evaluates to `"5"`, and so on.  Neither one actually alters the value of the variable `myString`.

To actually alter the value of the variable, you'd need to *assign* to that variable using Scheme's language form for assignment, `set!`.  (The `!` in the name is a Scheme convention, telling you that this is a *destructive* operation -- that is, one that destroys the previous value in `myString` and replaces it with a new one.)  For instance, you could write:

```
(define myString "")
(set! myString (string-append myString (number->string 4))) ;; assigns "4" to myString
(set! myString (string-append myString (number->string 5))) ;; assigns "45" to myString
(set! myString (string-append myString (number->string 6))) ;; assigns "456" to myString
(set! myString (string-append myString (number->string 7))) ;; assigns "4567" to myString
(display myString) ;; prints 4567
```

But you could, instead, just build up the expression you want in the first place instead of having to do all those destructive operations:

```
(define myString 
  (string-append (number->string 4) 
    (string-append (number->string 5) 
      (string-append (number->string 6) 
        (string-append (number->string 7) "")))))
(display myString) ;; prints 4567
```

And at that point, instead of writing code that's so repetitive, I'd do a `fold-right`:

```
(define myString 
  (fold-right (lambda (num str) 
                (string-append (number->string num) str)) 
    "" (list 4 5 6 7)))
(display myString) ;; prints 4567
```

If you have to assign `"4567"` to a global variable called `myString`, then you can simply replace `define` with `set!` in either of the above two code snippets.  However, although `set!` can come in handy at times, idiomatic Scheme tends to use `set!`s and other destructive operations sparingly.  I like to view the exclamation point as meaning "Proceed with caution!"

Comment: (set! myString (string-append myString (number->string 4)))

this is waht i was looking for , becasue the values being added on are going to be dynamic from a list/stack.  so your other options are more so for static information.

i ended up redesigning the program and used a global stack instead of a string (i know i should not have used any global data, but so be it - i am too used to OOP language)


Thank you!

Comment: Another thing you might try that would be more Schemely: `cons` the incoming values onto a list as they come in.  Then, later, if you need to spit them all out as a string, you could use something like the `fold-right` above.